# Determine whether a linear transformation is 1-1 and onto

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to know if my answers are right. For #1-3, determine if T is 1-1 and onto.

1. T: R3-->R2 defined by T(a1, a2, a3)=(a2,a3,a1)

a2=a3=a1=0 , N(T)=0 and V= N(T)+R(T) so R(T)=3. 1-1 but not onto since R(T) doesnt equal R2.

2. T:R3-->R3 defined by T(a1,a2,a3)=(a1-a2, a2-a3, a3-a1)

Basis for N(T)= (a3,a1,a1) so N(T)=2  R(T)=1. Not 1-1 and not onto since R(T) doesnt equal R3.

3. T:R3-->R3 defined by T(a,b)=(a,b,a+b)

a=b=0 so N(T)=0. R(T)=3 and R(T)=R3 so T is onto

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! In 1., the target should be $\Bbb R^3$, and in 3., the source should be $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Could you let us know what your notations like $N(T)$ and $R(T)$ are supposed to mean?

Comment: N(T) is the nullity or kernel and R(T) is the range or image

Comment: @ Bernard I don't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(1)$ is $1-1$ and onto ($\mathbb R^3$).

$(2)$ isn't, as you can check that the kernel is nontrivial.  $(1,1,1)$ is in the kernel,  for instance.

In $(3)$, $a=-b$, but $a=b=0$, for the kernel.  So yes, $1-1$.  But it can't be onto (dimensions).

Comment: For 1, I'm confused why its onto? I thought onto meant that R(T)= W ? So in 1, R(T)=3 , and W=R2 which dont equal each other.

Comment: I'm following this formula: nullity(T) + rank(T)= V

Comment: TYPO in my original post! Wrote R2 instead of R3.I see why Im confused now

Comment: The range should be $\mathbb R^3$, in $(1)$.  The Rank-nullity theorem is the right tool.

Comment: Likewise typo in $(3)$.  Domain is $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: For 3 Im confused. Why is it not onto ? (a,,b,a+b) = R3 and it matches rank(T) which is 3?

Comment: Yes Sorry !! I see my errors

Comment: Thank you Chris !!

Comment: Use the Rank-nullity theorem.   The domain should be $\mathbb R^2$, btw.  A linear transformation can't take a lower dimensional space onto a higher.